# INSERT in one table but it locks another table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, transactions, deadlock

I'm now having a problem with SQL Server table lock. I'm developing in C#.

My queries run under 1 transactions.

I name it for the easiest way to recognize.
"setTransaction"

setTransaction is only for "INSERT / UPDATE / DELETE".

- if I want to do `SELECT`. I'll use `SqlDataAdapter`.
- If I want to do `INSERT` / `UPDATE` or `DELETE`, it's the time to use `setTransaction`.

here is the table structure of each ...

```
[LOG](
    [log_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [subject] [text] NOT NULL,
    [query] [text] NOT NULL,
    [log_datetime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [user_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [emp_id] [int] NULL,
    [old_value] [text] NULL
)

[RESERVATION_DETAIL](
    [**reservation_detail_id**] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [reservation_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [spa_program_id] [int] NULL,
    [price] [int] NULL,
    [oil] [int] NULL
)

[RESERVATION_THERAPIST](
    [reservation_therapist_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [**reservation_detail_id**] [int] NOT NULL,
    [therapist_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [hours] [int] NULL,
    [mins] [int] NULL
)
```

[LOG] is working independently.
[RESERVATION_DETAIL] are connected to [RESERVATION_THERAPIST] via reservation_detail_id

The problem is ....

1. BEGIN TRANSACTION.
   I want to delete a record from "**RESERVATION_DETAIL**" with reservation_detail_id = 25
2. I select a record from "**RESERVATION_DETAIL**" with reservation_detail_id = 25

   SELECT * FROM RESERVATION_DETAIL WHERE RESERVATION_DETAIL_ID = 25
3. I insert into table "**LOG**" with data from 2.

   INSERT INTO LOG ( subject, query, log_datetime, user_id, emp_id, old_value ) VALUES (
        'DELETE TEMP RESERVE FROM RES_DETAIL[RES_DETAIL_ID:25]', 
        'DELETE FROM RESERVATION_DETAIL WHERE RESERVATION_DETAIL_ID = 25', 
        CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
        1, 
        NULL, 'reservation_detail_id:25|reservation_id:25|spa_program_id:-1|price:|oil:'
   )
4. now I delete from "**RESERVATION_DETAIL**" where reservation_detail_id = 25
   Then I want to delete a record from "**RESERVATION_THERAPIST**" with reservation_detail_id = 25

   DELETE FROM RESERVATION_DETAIL WHERE RESERVATION_DETAIL_ID = 25
5. I select a record from "**RESERVATION_THERAPIST**" with reservation_detail_id = 25 **<----- I GOT THE LOCK HERE !!**

   SELECT * FROM RESERVATION_THERAPIST WHERE RESERVATION_DETAIL_ID = 25
6. I insert into table "**LOG**" with data from 5.
7. Finally I will delete from "**RESERVATION_THERAPIST**" where reservation_detaiil_id = 25

Above steps were run consequently.
the step 5 (which is about table "**RESERVATION_THERAPIST**") is now wait on step 3 (about table "**LOG**") to finished but It never finished.

I don't understand why I insert into table **LOG** but it put the lock onto the table **B** !? or this is not a lock !?

there were the queries before the above step that insert into LOG without any problem.

---

Now I can solve my problem.

The queries and steps are already OK.

But I forgot that the table "RESERVATION_DETAIL" has a trigger that will run right after the DELETE query is committed.

So the trigger will go to delete a record in "RESERVATION_THERAPIST" automatically and this step is under the transaction.

So "RESERVATION_THERAPIST" was locked up after "DELETE FROM RESERVATION_DETAIL" but before I can "SELECT * FROM RESERVATION_THERAPIST"

Comment: WHY ARE WE YELLING?

Comment: How about you give the table structure in your post and the exact sql?

Comment: Are they difficult to read ?

Comment: @ChatawatL. yes. please edit the question with the structure

Comment: ok, I'm on it, Thank you so much

Comment: Please delete the three comments above that are attempts at showing table structure. Pretty much all the comments, actually.

Comment: I already added them to my question.
So sorry for misbehave. I'm newbie here.

Comment: If there's anything I can make it easier to read or if you want me to explain more. Please feel free to advise :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things could cause the table to be locked until the deletion is through:

1. You are directly deleting from the table you are trying to select from
2. You have cascade delete turned on for a parent table to the one that is locked.
3. You have a trigger on another table that you are taking an action from that also deletes from the table.
4. You are trying to delete the tables out of order (child table are always deleted first, then parent ones. When deleting from a parent table, it will check to see if child records exist. This of course takes longer than a straight delete and will cause a rollback if the child data exists which takes longer yet.
5. You have deadlock between two process running at the same time.

Comment: I found my answer at the same time you posted this one. But my reputation less than 10 so I cannot answer my own question. Then I accept yours :)

Answer (score 0):

You got the lock on B because you deleted from it.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I edited my question and put the real table name in it. :)